# Thread Lifecycle

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

1. Create a Student class with name, mark1, mark2, mark3 and sum variables.
2. Create an ArrayList with 4 student objects with some values.
3. Create a MarkEvaluation thread and ShowMark thread.
4. MarkEvaluation should perform the calculation of the total marks for each student.
5. ShowMark thread should display the calculated sum.
6. Use the join method to prevent the ShowMark thread to run before MarkEvaluation.

Its not homework.Part of some practice am doing.Here they asked me to run 2 threads doing different things but I don't know if we can run 2 run() methods.How can I perform 2 different operations? Sorry am just starting to learn threads.This is what I've done but it is incomplete.

```
import java.util.*;

class Student implements Runnable
 {
 public Student()
 {
     List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
     list.add("robin");
     list.add("ravi");
     list.add("raj");
     list.add("sam");
 }
 String name;
 int mark1=30,mark2=45,mark3=70,sum=0;

 public void run()
  {
    sum = mark1+mark2+mark3;
  }

}

public class Ch3Lu2Ex3
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Student stu = new Student();
    Thread MarkEvaluation = new Thread(stu);
    MarkEvaluation.start();
    Thread ShowMark = new Thread();

}
}
```

Comment: I just have some things to point out / comment on. Your objectives say some things and you seem to be doing different things. 1. Yes you do this correctly. Note: Does student have to implement Runnable / should student implement Runnable? 2. You create a list of STRINGS inside your student class. Is that what you want? Don't you want ArrayList<Student>? Shouldn't students be created in main? 3. MarkEvaluation thread should probably take in one Student in its constructor and calculate the sum of all the marks of a particular student (which it does but your student constructor is confusing).

Comment: I'm writing a solution about how I think it should be done. You've just mixed a lot of stuff together I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. What you want to do now is create another `Runnable` class for displaying the resulting sum, and you need to find some way of sharing the calculated sum from the `MarkEvaluation` thread. I suggest using a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), as the `take()` method will block until the `sum` has been `put` onto the thread, satisfying your last requirement without having to use `join()`.

Explicitly, you need 2 classes implementing `Runnable`, 1 you already have, and another for displaying the result. You need to share a `BlockingQueue` between them, and you need to start both threads by instantiating a `Thread` and calling `start()`. Hopefully this will put you on the right track without simply giving you the code.

Alternatively, you could have the `ShowMark` `Runnable` keep a reference to `Student` as well as the thread used to run `Student` (called `MarkEvaluation` above), `join` on the thread, and then call `getSum()` (or similar) to retrieve the sum from `Student`.

Comment: Oh thanks...I will look into it :) but they asked me to use join...how do I use that?

Comment: @Robin Updated my post. Also, for future reference, you're welcome to post homework questions on SO with well-reasoned attempts (as you have done).

Comment: Thank you so much :) I will try all what you told me :)

Answer (score 1):

Change it as

```
class Student implements Runnable {
...
}

class ShowMarkThread extends Thread {
    private final int sum;

    ShowMarkThread(int sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}

public class Ch3Lu2Ex3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Student stu = new Student();
        Thread markEvaluation = new Thread(stu);
        markEvaluation.start();
        markEvaluation.join();
        new ShowMarkThread(stu.sum).start();
    }
}
```

Besides, I suggest to make 2 separate classes - Student and MarkEvaluationThread, `Student implements Runnable` looks awful

Comment: Thanks a lot...I understood it properly from your way :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @dicarlo2, a BlockingQueue would also solve your problem. But I think you are going about this question in the wrong manner. Here is my multi-threaded solution. I have added a System.out.println statement in the ShowMark class so that we know that the magic is working. You will also see the students printed out of order, every now and then. I hope this helps!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(new Student("Alice", 10, 20, 30));
    students.add(new Student("Bob", 20, 30, 40));
    students.add(new Student("Carol", 30, 40, 50));
    students.add(new Student("Robin", 40, 50, 60));
    for (Student s : students) {
      Thread mkThread = new MarkEvaluation(s);
      mkThread.start();
      //Must at least start thread before starting ShowMark. 
      Thread smThread = new ShowMark(s, mkThread);
      smThread.start();
    }
  }

  private static class Student {
    String name;
    double mark1, mark2, mark3, sum;

    public Student(String name, double mark1, double mark2, double mark3) {
      this.name = name;
      this.mark1 = mark1;
      this.mark2 = mark2;
      this.mark3 = mark3;
    }
  }

  private static class MarkEvaluation extends Thread {
    Student stu;
    public MarkEvaluation(Student stu) {
      this.stu = stu;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      super.run();
      stu.sum = stu.mark1 + stu.mark2 + stu.mark3;
    }
  }

  private static class ShowMark extends Thread {
    Thread thread;
    Student stu;
    public ShowMark(Student stu, Thread thread) {
      this.stu = stu;
      this.thread = thread;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      super.run();
      // A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.
      while (thread.isAlive()) {
        try {
          System.out.println("Waited for thread: " + thread.toString() + " to finish.");
          thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      System.out.println(stu.name + " " + stu.sum);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D your way is very clear...I got it :) I just haven't learnt so much so as to be able to do all this...now I will learn...thanks :)